# Please make the font and color settings in the snippet editor match the result in the question's code block

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, syntax-highlighting

I only noticed today that there is mismatch between the display in the StackSnippet editor:

[image]

and the resulting HTML in the code block in the question:

[image]

First of all, the color coding is different, and secondly, the font families aren't the same.

Is this by design? If not, would it be possible to use the same colors and font for both?

Comment: it seems the same for me (last chrome version - windows 8.1 (64bit))

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, that depends on your configuration. In the editor, the font is `monospace`. In the question, it's `Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, sans-serif;` which may come out looking the same, if you're lucky!